# generate bash script in python by passing vars

Tags: python, bash, csv

I am trying in python to generate a bash script by passing vars from CSV file. any one have an idea, please?

Example:
I want to pass row[0] and row[1] from a csv file
csv:
**source**, **destination**
London, Paris

the resulted bash script for example:
" the train is going from "London" to " Paris"

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem? Inserting variables into a string is trivial in Python

Comment: This wouldn’t be considered a bash script, just a plain old python script.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Make sure you read the guidelines for how questions are asked. Clarity is key an. Share data for reproducibility, and any attempt you have done to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a file `routes.csv` with a list of routes:

```txt
source,destination
London,Paris
Paris,Amsterdam
Amsterdam,London
```

And a template of a bash script `route.sh.tpl`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "the train is going from \""{{source}}"\" to \""{{destination}}"\""
```

Then here is a short example that instantiates a template with the data from the csv file and then executes the generated file.

```python
import csv
import subprocess
import shlex
import jinja2

CSV_FILE='routes.csv'
BASH_FILE='routes.sh'
TPL_FILE='routes.sh.tpl'

with open(CSV_FILE, 'r') as csv_file:
    template = jinja2.Template(open(TPL_FILE).read())
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for row in reader:
        for key,value in row.items():
            row[key] = shlex.quote(value)  # prevent unsafe inputs
        with open(BASH_FILE, 'w') as bash_file:
            bash_file.write(template.render(**row))
        subprocess.call(['/bin/bash', BASH_FILE])
```

---

**Update** following a comment from Charles Duffy. Passing the data read from an external file to shell may be prone to abuse. With Python 3 `shlex` module this example can be made safer by using `shlex.quote`.

Consider a malicious input

```text
source,destination
London,Paris
Paris,Amsterdam
Amsterdam,$(rm -f testfile; echo London)
```

If the output looks as it was with the original input, then the system had been compromised. The correct output with this input should look like.

```text
the train is going from "London" to "Paris"
the train is going from "Paris" to "Amsterdam"
the train is going from "Amsterdam" to "$(rm -f testfile; echo London)"
```

Comment: If you don't use `shlex.quote` to escape the values before they're inserted into bash, a CSV with `$(rm -rf ~)` as a destination would be very dangerous.

Comment: (though -- if using that, the insertions should be into an _unquoted_ shell context to ensure that the quotes that `shlex.quote` (or `pipes.quote` in Python 2) adds are treated as syntax rather than data; so f/e, `echo "the train is going from \""{{source}}"\" to \""{{destination}}"\""`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for this comment. At least this seems to make this code safer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is what I need. I appreciate your help